# session_id not working with session_name

Tags: php, sessionid

I am using the session_name to rename my session to lets says 'xxx'. Using this I am also able to start a session using session_start. I also able see the cookie being set in my browser.

//TO SET session

### login.php

```
session_name('xxx');
session_start();
```

But the problem is that I am not able to retrieve the session id using the session_id call in an another script.

### another.php

```
session_name('xxx');

$id = session_id();
echo $id // This is showing empty

var_dump($_COOKIE) // This is showing the cookie xxx with the session id 

if(!empty($id))
{
  //If he is already logged in, lets get his details
  session_start();
}
```

I know that I can go ahead and read the cookie to see if the session is set. But I was just curious to know why this is not working. Isn't the session_id function retrieve my session id after setting the session_name ?

We know the that session_start is going to open my existing session but on the other hand if at all there isn't session then it will start a new one. I don't want start a new session if it is not already started.

What am I  doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no `session_id` before you start the session with `session_start`.
`session_name` just sets the cookie/URL param name, it does not start a session.

And yes, you need to `start()` the session on every single page you want to use it.

Comment: How do we know if the session is already started. We have to do a pre check right?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what `session_start` does. It *initiates the session system within PHP*. It does *not* "begin" a *new* session. If there's already an existing session for the current user, `session_start` will start the session system with that existing session. Therefore, you need to call it on every page.